# Do I still have to use a template DB for PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0

```
createdb mydb -T template_postgis
```

Is this `-T template_postgis` still necessary in new versions of PostGIS?

I never saw this db being different, it always has those 3 sql files you run there. Is this still necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You no longer need to use the templates or even the script in the new versions of Postgis. As you can see in the [Postgis - installation page](http://postgis.net/install/), all you need is run the CREATE EXTENTION command.

```sql
-- Enable PostGIS (includes raster)
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
-- Enable Topology
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
-- fuzzy matching needed for Tiger
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
-- Enable US Tiger Geocoder
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
```

Answer (score 0):

I never use it, simply create a new DB from basic Postgresql template:

```
CREATE DATABASE pgis_template TEMPLATE template0;
```

Then i load and run scripts postgis.sql and spatial_ref_sys.sql for your basic setup. I then use this template DB for all the others i create

Comment: you do the same as I. then you use `create database newdb template=pgis_template`. Just as I do this from system shell: `createdb newdb -T pgis_template`. Same thing.